# c++ multiple regex extractions to an array

Tags: c++

I'm having to extract multiple values from a string within c++. I can do this fine in python, but unfortunately for me, this must be done in c++.

If, for example I have the string below contained in 'blah', how do I run a multiple extraction regex against it and pass each numerical value into an array.
I'm fine with the regex, just not the c++ syntax.

std::string blah = "5001 | 5002 | 5003";

Thank you

Comment: Have you check the [regular expression library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) in the standard library? What have you tried? What did you have problems with?

Comment: Regex string: "^(\\d+ \\| )*(\\d+)$"

Comment: A regular expression is overkill here. Just use `std::istringstream`, or parse it yourself with `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++11, regular expressions are part of the C++ standard library. Alternatively, you can use *boost-regex*. The APIs are almost identical except for the namespaces. You can it as follows:

```
auto blah = std::string{"5001 | 5002 | 5003"};
auto values = std::vector<std::string>{
    std::sregex_token_iterator{blah.begin(), blah.end(), std::regex{R"(\d+)"}},
    std::sregex_token_iterator{}};
```

If you need `int` instead of `std::string`, use `std::stoi` to convert the strings into integers.

Comment: The shown code does not compile anymore. C++14 forbids temporary regexes, see core issue [2332](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2332). Need to hoist `std::regex{R"(\d+)"}` out into a separate variable.